# Get comments in a PHP file

Tags: php, parsing, comments

I've been trying to get the comments out of a certain `.php` file on my server, in order to parse its variables. I thought Ii found an easy way to do this, however, the function I use doesn't return anything, even though I clearly have comments in the file.

Here are the comments I use:

```
/**
* @param  foo bar
* @return baz
*/
```

Here's my code:

```
function GetComments($filename) {

    $expr = "/((?:\/\*(?:[^*]|(?:\*+[^*\/]))*\*+\/)|(?:\/\/.*))/";

    $file = fopen($filename, "r");
    $length = filesize($filename);
    $comments = fread($file, $length);
    fclose($file);

    preg_match_all($expr, $comments, $matches);

    foreach($matches[0] as $id => $variable) {
        $comments = str_replace($variable, '', $comments);
    }

    return $comments;
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Because if so, I'm clearly over looking it.

Any help would be very welcome.

---

I found an answer:

First of all, I should have probably noted in my question that I am trying to write a system for reading plugins. These plugin files should contain a comment block at the top containing variables like the plugin's author, website, email, etc.

So here's what I did:

I took feeela's example to change my function to get the comments and its variables.

I then changed its code a bit to fit my needs:

```
public function GetComments($filename)
{

    $docComments = array_filter(token_get_all(file_get_contents($filename)), function($entry)
    {
        return $entry[0] == T_COMMENT;
    });
    $fileDocComment = array_shift($docComments);

    $regexp = "/\@.*\:\s.*\r/";
    preg_match_all($regexp, $fileDocComment[1], $matches);

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($matches[0]); $i++)
    {
        $params[$i] = split(": ", $matches[0][$i]);
    }

    return($params);
}
```

I put the result of the code feeela gave me through a regular expression match, resulting in an array containing the parameters and their values combined.

Then I used the split function to actually give me separated parameters and values, so I could return them to the variable that called the function.

In order to get this to work properly, I needed to change the comment style I used from

```
/**
* @param foo bar
* @return baz
*/
```

to

```
/*
@param: foo bar
@return: baz
*/
```

making it a normal comment block, instead of a doc comment block.
And it also enabled me to use ': ' as a pattern for the split function.

It might be 'not so efficient' in the eyes of some. As feeela noted, "what if your comment style changes?". I will be the only one working on this project and writing the plugins. Therefore it will not be too hard for me too keep the comment style the same in every plugin script.

This method works perfectly for me.

Comment: what does it print when u do print_r($matches); ??

Comment: You cannot use regular expressions to reliably accomplish this.

Comment: don't mind the backslashes in front of my parameters, because i needed to put them there since SO thought i was notifying somebody in this comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => /** * \@param foo bar * \@return baz */ ) [1] => Array ( [0] => /** * \@param foo bar * \@return baz */ ) )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [token_get_all()](http://php.net/token_get_all), which "parses a given PHP source string into language tokens using the Zend engine's lexical scanner".

Here's an example function I've used once to get the file-doc-comment from the current file:

```
/**
 * Return first doc comment found in this file.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function getFileDocBlock()
{
    $docComments = array_filter(
        token_get_all( file_get_contents(__FILE__)), function($entry) {
            return $entry[0] == T_DOC_COMMENT;
        }
    );
    $fileDocComment = array_shift($docComments);
    return $fileDocComment[1];
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks. this got me the actual block of comments that i used in the file (when i changed '__FILE__' to the filename i wanted). so now i guess i have to use some regexp to pull out the variables.

Comment: @Gabi Barrientos Instead of doing some wild parsing, you should define in your question, what exactly you want to achieve. There are probably easier ways to get the information you want to retrieve. Also, try the `token_get_all()`-function without filtering its output to see what other infos are included. For example if you want to get the function params – they have their own value in the returned array from `token_get_all()`.

Answer (score 3):

Try using *[The ReflectionClass class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php)* and *[The ReflectionFunction class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php)*.

This all is you need to get function parameters.

Comment: Only for class methods though, not a normal function.

Comment: So You say this example doesn't work at all ? http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php#105367

Comment: This is not much more than a link-only answer. Can you [elaborate](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11504589/edit) a little bit in your answer? E.g., use them in what way? What would an example look look? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Comment Manager](https://www.pakjiddat.pk/articles/view/254/comment-manager). It is a set of PHP classes for parsing [DocBloc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docblock#PHP) comments. It also allows validating function parameter values against information in DocBlock comments.