# Regular expression failed

Tags: php, regex

I have this text:

```
/**
 * @var \guervyl\cbind_attr_testBundle\Entity\Category
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="guervyl\cbind_attr_testBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="song")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $category;

/**
 * @var \guervyl\cbind_attr_testBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="guervyl\cbind_attr_testBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="song")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $user;
```

I want to get that part to edit:

```
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="guervyl\cbind_attr_testBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="song")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $category;
```

I have that expression that stop on the `$`: `(\*.*@ORM\\ManyToOne\(.*)(\)(?:\s|.)*?private \$)`

But when I try to select the rest `category;`, when I set the c I got no match (timeout): `(\*.*@ORM\\ManyToOne\(.*)(\)(?:\s|.)*?private \$c)`

I want that regex to work: `(\*.*@ORM\\ManyToOne\(.*)(\)(?:\s|.)*?private \$category;)`

What's wrong with my Regex?

Comment: Does this have to do with regex in php? Or is the tag for php just cause the files you are digging in are php?

Comment: Try [`(\*.*@ORM\\ManyToOne\(.*)(\)[\S\s]*?private \$\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/7A9g9I/1).

Comment: @Randall It's just for Regex. It's not for a specific programing language

Comment: Change `(?:\s|.)*?` to `(?>\s|.)*?` or more better `\X*?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your regex result has the same result as mine. I want my regex to select until `category;` like: `(\*.*@ORM\\ManyToOne\(.*)(\)(?:\s|.)*?private \$category;)`

Comment: @revo can you please write the full modified regex? Because I got error with `(\*.*@ORM\\ManyToOne\(.*)(\)(?>\s|.)*?private \$)` and `(\*.*@ORM\\ManyToOne\(.*)(\)\X*?private \$)` does not work.

Comment: What error do you get? [I can't reproduce.](https://regex101.com/r/NPl3g4/2)

Comment: I see you removed the PHP tag, so this is not a PHP question. PHP itself provides some built-in reflection classes that [allow you to parse docblocks](https://eval.in/897736). Also, since these are Doctrine Annotations - I believe Doctrine Core has Annotation parsing classes - could be useful for reference.

Comment: I am testing the regex at https://regexr.com/ . The error is `Invalid target for quantifier`

Comment: Regexr regex engine differs from the one provided in regex101 live demo hence no support of atomic groups. A globally available alternative would be changing `(?:\s|.)*?` to `[\s\S]*?`.

Comment: @DarraghEnright I didn't know if can get the comments from PHP. It wroked. You just save my day.

Comment: @revo it worked with `[\s\S]*?`

Comment: @user3502626 That is what my pattern was about: [`(\*.*@ORM\\ManyToOne\(.*)(\)[\S\s]*?private \$category;)`](https://regex101.com/r/7A9g9I/2) - I used `[\s\S]` instead of `(?:\s|.)`

Comment: isn't it easier to get doc comments [by reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.getdoccomment.php)?

Comment: @user3502626 glad it helped? I can post it as an answer if you want?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you were right. I just +1 you. But why `(?:\s|.)` did not work?

Comment: @DarraghEnright do it. It's yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matching pattern could be:

```
.*ManyToOne(.|\n)*category;
```

The pattern means:

```
.*           Match anything zero or more times
ManyToOne    Literally match "ManyToOne"
(.|\n)*      Match anything (including line breaks) zero or more times
category;    Literally match "category;"
```

The resulting match would be:

```
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="guervyl\cbind_attr_testBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="song")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $category;
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](http://regexr.com/3h5ek)

Comment: It just selected it, but my regex was just to replace what is inside `@ORM\ManyToOne(...)`

Comment: RegEx is not used to replace a String, only to match a pattern. You would use your primary programming language to do the replacing.

Comment: Yes, you can use capturing group inside your regex pattern to be able to do the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to get comments out of a PHP file using regex? Not sure if you're aware, but PHP includes functions for parsing the language which allow you to grab the comments (and other parts of the code) very easily without any regex at all.

The function you're looking for is [`token_get_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php), and you can get some example code that does exactly what you want [from this answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504541/get-comments-in-a-php-file).